# hanging observable blocking router when it is "cached"

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I am trying to consume my service in a `ngrx/effect` to load the data in when requested, but cache the request for efficiency. I have read a few examples which use this method of storing the observable and giving it back again if exists, and giving the `publishReplay` `refCount` to redo the response of the request without sending it.

This all seems to work perfectly - however after the first request, if I reuse the cached observable the `Angular` router stops working. Which again from reading, is down to it waiting for the promise of the observable to complete?

How can I setup the consumption of my service to resolve correctly?

I have a helper service for getting data out of my API, and I'm trying to cache the responses like this:

```
  getResource(params) {
    if (!this.cache[cacheKey]) {
      this.cache[cacheKey] = this.api.get(RESOURCE_URL, params)
        .pipe(
          publishReplay(1),
          refCount(),
        );
    }
    return this.cache[cacheKey];
  }
```

(the get method on the api service looks something like this)

```
  get(resource, params?: object): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(resource, params);
  }
```

And the effect looks like this:

```
  @Effect()
  search$: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType<Search>(Types.SEARCH),
    debounceTime(300),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(state => state.search_properties)),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(([payload, store]) => {

      this.store.dispatch(new GlobalActions.SearchStarted());

      const params = merge({include: ['latestPrint']}, store);

      return this.lookupService
        .getResource(params)
        .pipe(
          map((response: ApiResponse) => {
            this.store.dispatch(new GlobalActions.SearchComplete());
            return new ResultActions.SetSearchResults(response);
          }),
          catchError(() => of(new GlobalActions.EffectError()))
        );
    })
  );
```